# Dev page showing up all the time on index page

Tags: shopify, remix.run, shopify-storefront-api, shopify-hydrogen

Even after setting the `.env` file, I keep having the dev home page on my store. I need to go to `http://localhost:3000/index` to be able to see the actual index page I created. How can I remove it?

The shopify hydrogen docs suggest that this shouldn't appear once you set the `.env` correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Remix is changing their routing name conventions, and the hydrogen docs are not correctly updated yet.

You need to use `_index.tsx` instead of `index.tsx`to solve it.